# String.replace(x,x,count => 1) in Python

Tags: python, replace, syntax

I am new to python and learning it. In my project code I saw in the replace function the count is given in this format. When I run in Python editor it gives this error.

```
"Bharath..Bharath..Bharath".replace("..", ".", count => 1)
```

```sh
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py", line 147, in compile
    raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError:   File "./prog.py", line 1

    x="Bharath..Bharath..Bharath".replace("..", ".", count => 1)

                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone tell me what this count => 1 means i understand that the last parameter is the no of occurrences to replace.

Thanks

Comment: Just try count=1 or just 1. “..”.replace(“..”,”.”,1)

Answer (score 0):

In Python this can be done very easily `String.replace(StringToReplace, ReplaceWith, Count)`

For your example

`x="Bharath..Bharath..Bharath".replace("..", ".", 1)`should work. Keywords like "count" dont work here.

So you were close to the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace method does not take keyword arguments so, just update your code with following code.

```
"Bharath..Bharath..Bharath".replace("..", ".", 1)
```